# How to clear Dropdown using Angular Material

Tags: angular

I am beginner of Angular Material. I run into the problem, when I click clear button. The button doesn't clear the dropwn, why is that? I tried:

**Form**

```
<mat-form-field class="custom-form-field" name="active"  
  [(ngModel)]="active" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
>
  <mat-label>Choose an option</mat-label>
  <select matNativeControl >
    <mat-option [value]="null">selected</mat-option>
    <option value="1">True</option>
    <option value="2">False</option>
  </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Initial active value: `active: string = "";`
Code to clear the dropdown: `this.active = '';`

**Clear Button**

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="custom-button"(click)="clear()">
  Clear
</button>
```

Comment: I do not see a clear button in your code. Also `null` !== `''`. Additionally, why are you mixing `option` and `mat-option`?

Comment: i added the clear button